# SQL Conditional Print Statement

Tags: sql

I am working on two different tables: `sales` and `inventory`. From the table `inventory`, there's `Quantity_Received` and from the table `sales`, there's `Quantity_Sold`.
`Quantity Remaining in Store` represents the difference between `Quantity_Received` and `Quantity_Sold`.

When the `Quantity Remaining in Store` is equal to 0, I want SQL to print 'Out of stock'.
When the `Quantity Remaining in Store` is greater than 0 but less than 10, I want SQL to print `Low stock`.
When the `Quantity Remaining in Store` is greater than 10, I want SQL to print `Still in stock`

Here is the query I am using currently:

```
SELECT
    inventory.Quantity_Received AS 'Q1',
    sales.Quanity_Sold as 'Q2',
    inventory.Quantity_Received - sales.Quanity_Sold as 'Quantiy Remaining in Store'
FROM inventory
INNER JOIN sales
    ON inventory.id=sales.id
IF (inventory.Quantity_Received - sales.Quanity_Sold =>10),
BEGIN,
PRINT 'Still enough in Stock',
END
ELSE IF (inventory.Quantity_Received - sales.Quanity_Sold =<10)
BEGIN
PRINT 'Low in Stock'
END
IF (inventory.Quantity_Received - sales.Quanity_Sold =0),
BEGIN,
PRINT 'Out of stock'
```

Comment: Use a case expression.

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like

```
SELECT
    inventory.Quantity_Received AS 'Q1',
    sales.Quanity_Sold as 'Q2',
    inventory.Quantity_Received - sales.Quanity_Sold as 'Quantity Remaining in Store',
    CASE 
        WHEN (inventory.Quantity_Received - sales.Quanity_Sold >10) THEN 'Still enough in Stock'
        WHEN (inventory.Quantity_Received - sales.Quanity_Sold =<10 AND inventory.Quantity_Received - sales.Quanity_Sold > 0) THEN 'Low in Stock'
    ELSE 'Out of Stock'
    END as Quantity_Remaining_in_Store
from inventory
inner join sales on inventory.id=sales.id
```

Comment: Should be `> 0) THEN 'Low in Stock'`.

Comment: Oops, read my comment one more time. (As it is now, you'll never reach out of stock.)

Comment: Thanks so much... I worked now...All I did was to change this  WHEN (inventory.Quantity_Received - sales.Quanity_Sold =<10  to  WHEN (inventory.Quantity_Received - sales.Quanity_Sold <10... I am really grateful